# What are the equations of motion for Electrodynamics when the gauge field does not vanish at radial infinity?

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, boundary-conditions

TLDR: If the gauge field $A^{\mu}(x)$ does not vanish at $r\rightarrow \infty$ the variation of the Maxwell Lagrangian gives rise to (1). What are the correct equations of motion, or how does one handle the system when the term (1) does not vanish?

When we derive the Euler-Lagrange equations of motion from a Lagrangian in a field theory, we perform an integration by parts, and neglect a term at the boundary, i.e.
\begin{align}
\delta S&=\int_{\mathcal{M}} d^4x\bigg(\frac{\delta L}{\delta\phi}\delta\phi+\frac{\delta L}{\delta(\partial_{\mu}\phi)}\delta(\partial_{\mu}\phi)\bigg)\\
&=\int_{\mathcal{M}} d^4x\bigg(\frac{\delta L}{\delta\phi}\delta\phi+\partial_{\mu}\bigg(\frac{\delta L}{\delta(\partial_{\mu}\phi)}\delta\phi\bigg)-\partial_{\mu}\frac{\delta L}{\delta (\partial_{\mu}\phi)}\delta\phi\bigg)
\end{align}
where $\mathcal{M}$ is Minkowski space. Combining the first and third term and setting $\delta S=0$ we obtain the Euler-Lagrange equations, if we ignore the middle term. We usually ignore the middle term by saying that because it is a total derivative, Stokes theorem tells us that we can evaluate it at the boundary of the manifold, and then we assume that the fields vanish at said boundary and so we can ignore this term. Lets not ignore this middle term just yet and write it as (using Stokes theorem):
\begin{equation}
\oint_{\partial\mathcal{M}} d^3x \,\,\,n_{\mu} \bigg(\frac{\delta L}{\delta(\partial_{\mu}\phi)}\delta\phi\bigg)
\end{equation}
where $n_{\mu}$ is the normal vector to $\partial\mathcal{M}$. Now typically in an initial value problem we specify the field at some initial time $\phi_i(t_i,\vec{x})$ and final time $\phi_f(t_f,\vec{x})$, so we will not consider variations $\delta\phi$ that vary the fields at $t_i$ and $t_f$. Therefore this boundary term takes the form:
\begin{equation}
\int_{t_i}^{t_f}dt\oint_{r=\infty}d\theta d\phi \,\,\,r^2\sin\theta \,\,\,\hat{r}_{i} \bigg(\frac{\delta L}{\delta(\partial_{i}\phi)}\delta\phi\bigg)
\end{equation}
where $\hat{r}_i$ is the unit radial vector which is orthogonal to the relevant part of $\partial \mathcal{M}$. Lets now specialize to free Maxwell electrodynamics $L=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$. We then have that this boundary term takes the form:
\begin{equation}
\int_{t_i}^{t_f}dt\oint_{r=\infty}d\theta d\phi \,\,\,r^2\sin\theta \,\,\,\hat{r}_{i} \bigg(F^{i\alpha}\delta A_{\alpha}\bigg)\hspace{40pt} (1)
\end{equation}
Now it need not be the case that this vanishes. For example if $F^{i\alpha}\sim \frac{1}{r^2}$ then this term need not vanish. Question: In the case that this term does not vanish, what are the equations of motion for free electrodynamics? Or, what is the appropriate way to handle the system in this case?

Comment: Sounds like a field one would reject on being unphysical to me.

Comment: If your field is pure gauge, $F$ still vanishes so you are fine. Are you specifically interested in the case when the physical field is non-zero?

Comment: Yes, consider the case when the field on the boundary isnt just pure gauge.